# How can I store a feeder value in a varaible to reuse it

Tags: string, scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a feeder containing some data, for example:

name
jack
jim
jomana

And I want to send a request that simulate the name search action

1- user start to enter the fisrt letter of the name

2- then the 3 other letters

so the requests that I want to send :
get ( https/bla/bla/search?q=here I want only the first letter of the name)

get ( https/bla/bla/search?q=here I want only the 3 first letters of the name)

I know that substring(start,end) works well but my problem how can I apply it on "${name}"
because when I do "${name}".substring(0,1) => in this situation "${name}" doesn't retrive name value "jack"

Infos: I m using scala with gatling

when I do "${name}".substring(0,1) => in this situation "${name}" doesn't retrive name value "jack"

Comment: Try it with prepending an `s` to the string `s"$name".substring(0,1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create additional action with logic which will produce the values that you need:

```scala
    .exec { session =>
      val name = session("name").as[String]

      val firstPartOfName = name.substring(0, 1)
      val secondPartOfName = name.substring(1, 4)

      session
        .set("firstPartOfName", firstPartOfName)
        .set("secondPartOfName", secondPartOfName)
    }
    .exec("...search?q=${firstPartOfName}")
    .exec("...search?q=${secondPartOfName}")
```